# Unit Testing: Is it valid to do a minimal test?

Tags: unit-testing, mockito

I have a basic question about unit tests.  I found a crash in my code, and I wrote a test to reproduce the bug.  I then fixed the bug and verified that it passes the test.  My question, is if I took the best approach.  Here is a simplified example:

```
public class ClassC
{
    private int internalFlag;

    void all(Dependency dep1, Dependency dep2, Dependency dep3, Dependency dep4)
    {
        a(dep1);
        b(dep2)
        c(dep3)
        d(dep4)
        e();
        f();
    }

    void e()
    {
        if (some logic based on dep3)
        {
            internalFlag = 2;
        }
    }

    void f()
    {
        if (internalFlag == 2)
        {
            Log("All is well");
        }
        else
        {
            Log("Crash occurs")
        }
    }
}
```

In the above example, I have a method called "all" that calls methods a, b, c, d, e, f.  Now, I found a crash in "f" because the "internalVar" was not an expected value.  This 'internalVar" was set in "e", but as you can see "e" does not set the internalFalg to anything if the condition is false.  So the bug is in e.

I was able to write the test to isolate the bug.  Then I fixed the bug and found that the test past.  Thats great, but in order to do it I had to do something like:

```
void testAll()
{
    mockDep1 = mock(dep1);
    mockDep2 = mock(dep2);
    mockDep3 = mock(dep3);
    mockDep4 = mock(dep4);

    all(mockDep1, mockDep2, mockDep3, mockDep4);
}
```

Now the part where I make mockDep1..4 is very simple here in this example, but it was actually very long laborious code.  My question is, is it valid instead just to do the minimal calls to reproduce the crash:

```
void testCrash()
{
   mockDep3 = mock(dep3);
   c(mockDep3)    
   e()
   f();
}
```

This would be all I would be required to do to reproduce and test the crash, except that its not exactly how the code would be called in the actual method "all", that calls each method.  It just seems like writing testAll above including all the mocks over and over again for each bug is a bit tedius.  But then again, thats how the actual method "all" would work.  So is it better instead to isolate the bug, even if the isolation is not exactly how it would work if the full method was called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's not clear from your example is which of the methods are public and which are private (or protected or package-private).  If the only public method is the one called `all`, then wherever possible, this is the one that your tests should call, unless you're testing complex logic that really is contained in just one of the methods.

When you choose which tests to write, you should really focus on what the contract of this class is.  What functionality does the rest of your application expect this class to provide?  Base your test methods on what that functionality is; not on which methods you happen to have written.

Moreover, if the only purpose of the Dependency class is to support the functionality of ClassC, then you might consider writing tests whose SUT is this ClassC and Dependency together (some would call these "integration tests", some would call them "unit tests, where the unit consists of two classes").

In your particular case, it seems that your class is providing functionality that runs right across the division into methods.  So test the functionality - and test the different scenarios that may cause the functionality to work differently.  Don't test the individual methods.  In particular, you'll have a number of tests that call the `all` method in various scenarios; some of which lead to the error occurring (at least before you fix the bug) and some of which do not.

Lastly, to help you think in terms of testing functionality and scenarios, I believe that you should name your test methods according to the functionality and scenario that are being exercised, not by the method that is being called.  In particular, I consider `testAll` (in fact, any name that consists of `test` followed by the name of a method) to be a poor name for a test method.  But maybe that's something to think about on another day.

Comment: I think I understand what you are saying, but perhaps I am not liking the answer.  I guess you are saying that I will have to make a number of calls to "all", supplying different mocks to trigger different paths, one to generate the crash.  I guess I find it somewhat tedious to build all those mocks over and over for each test just to get to the crash, when I can just call e() and f() directly to trigger the crash and test the fix.  But in this case you are right, e() and f() SHOULD be private, so that wouldn't be an option.  It just seems like a difficult way of testing.

Comment: I normally use [Mockito annotations](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#9) to create my mocks, so that I don't have to re-code them for each test.  If there's particular stubbing that all the mocks need, I'll usually set that up in a method that has the JUnit `@Before` tag.

Comment: I'm using Mockito as well, though I'm new to it.  Do you mean anything special when you say "annotations" or just refering to the typical mockito command like mock() doAnswer() etc?  I think you are right, maybe I can simplify my tests a bit if I take advantage of the "setup" method, which I assume is similar to the @Before tag you mention.

Comment: I assume that you're using JUnit 4, in which case any method can be tagged with the `@Before` annotation, which makes it run before every test method. Of course, you can still call it `setUp`, which is the JUnit 3 equivalent. If you call `initMocks()` in your @Before method (which is a static method in the `MockitoAnnotations` class), Mockito will look for fields in your test class that have the `@Mock` annotation, and make them all into mock objects. Did you read the link in my previous comment?  It has an example. I find this easier to work with than explicitly creating every mock.

Comment: I see.  Thanks for posting the help David, very useful!